# If 'no results' echo...?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a basic form to filter a database. The first section works like a dream:

```
$result=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM performers WHERE accent='$txt_accent' AND hair='$txt_hair' AND gender='$txt_gender' AND location='$txt_location'");


$result->execute();

echo '<table><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr>';

while($row=$result->fetch())   {


echo '<tr><td>'.$row['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>';

                                                    }
echo '</table>';
```

But I can not get the php to echo out "No results" if there are no matches.  At the moment I am trying variations of the following after the query:

```
if ($result= FALSE) {
echo 'No results';
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this is incorrect -> `if ($result= FALSE) {
echo 'No results';
    }` it should be `if (!$result) {
echo 'No results';
    }` OR `if ($result == FALSE) {
echo 'No results';
    }`

Comment: No, doesn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: Which api is used to connect and query with? Mysqli or PDO? What are the variables' values and origin?

Comment: what are you using, pdo or mysqli?

Comment: *"I can not get the php to echo out "No results" if there are no matches"* - You have to make it so that your query did fail in order to get that. I honestly don't know why you're wanting to do that or what the question is really about, so I'll vote this one as "unclear".

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fetchAll` in a variable :

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll();

if (empty($rows)) {
  echo 'No results';
} else {
  foreach($rows as $row) {
    // display results
  }
}
```

Comment: Where would I insert this? It doesn't seem to work at all.